# How do I access fields of a *mut libc::FILE?

Tags: rust, libc

I'm trying to access the different fields of the `FILE` struct of `libc`.

`FILE` implementation in Rust according to the memory mapping in `stdio.h`:

```
#[repr(C)]
pub struct FILE {
    pub _p: libc::c_char,
    pub _r: libc::c_int,
    pub _w: libc::c_int,
    pub _flags: libc::c_short,
    pub _file: libc::c_short,
    ...
}
```

when working with `FILE`s in libc they come in the `mut *` variant, and this somehow is in the way to access the fields. The following code triggers `error: attempted access of field`_flags`on type '*mut FILE', but no field with that name was found`.

```
let stdout = libc::fdopen(libc::STDOUT_FILENO, &('w' as libc::c_char));
let is_unbuffered = (fp._flags & libc::_IONBF as i16) != 0
```

A variable of type `FILE` without the `mut *` variant works but I need to get it working with `mut *`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`FILE`](https://github.com/rust-lang/libc/blob/0.2.14/src/lib.rs#L133) is defined as an [opaque type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ffi.html#representing-opaque-structs), that is:

```
pub enum FILE {}
```

So there is no field to access (even dereferencing the raw pointer).

---

I think it is not a good idea to access the fields of `FILE` structure directly, even in C. You should try to find a function on [`stdio.h`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_file_input/output) that do what you want.

---

Anyway, one workaround is to create your own definition of `FILE` and get a `&mut` from `fp`:

```
#[repr(C)]
pub struct MY_FILE {
    pub _p: libc::c_char,
    pub _r: libc::c_int,
    pub _w: libc::c_int,
    pub _flags: libc::c_short,
    pub _file: libc::c_short,
    // ...
}

// ...

unsafe {
    let fp = libc::fdopen(libc::STDOUT_FILENO, &('w' as libc::c_char));
    let fp = &mut *(fp as *mut MY_FILE);
    let is_unbuffered = (fp._flags & libc::_IONBF as i16) != 0;
}
```

Note that if you do not use the correct definition for `MY_FILE`, you will get some garbage data or even a segfault.

Comment: thank you. the `&mut *` bit was the missing part in my code. Can you shed any light on what this does? I'm still in the dark when it comes to pointers and references, really hard coming from a Java/PHP/Python world

Comment: additional question: my struct now "doesn't work": `_flags` is always 0. Do you have any hints in how to fix that? Here's stdio.h on OSX: https://gist.github.com/philippkeller/3921705e7b5d0ef5d394501496d146fe 
I just don't see what the problem is, IMO to access _flags directly all members up and with `_flags` need to be correct, the following ones can be wrong (or even left out)

Comment: `fdopen` returns a [raw pointer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.pointer.html). You cannot do much with a raw pointer, so we get a mutable reference (`&mut`) from it (`*` dereference the pointer, which gives a value of type `FILE`, `&mut` get a mutable reference to the `FILE` value). I think it is not a good idea to access the fields of `FILE` structure directly, even in `C`. Maybe you should ask another question explaining what you want to do (test if a file is buffered?).

Comment: thanks for the pointer explanation. I'm slowly getting the hang of it. About my intention: it's purely educational, I'm trying to port [this C program](https://gist.github.com/philippkeller/20f293f669efbd192ffa0da91f6ea1b5) to Rust (example in the book "Advanced Programming for Unix Environment")

Comment: That's interesting. In this case, I recommend you to use [`bindgen`](https://github.com/Yamakaky/rust-bindgen) to generated the correct `FILE` definition. You can run it on the `.h` file and copy the generated `FILE` definition.

Comment: thanks, I'm now a step further, but the resulting struct seems to be off somehow, I opened this new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39169146/wrong-mapping-of-c-struce-to-rust-struct

Answer (score 0):

The pointer itself doesn't have attributes, the struct it points to does.

So what this means is that you need to access `*fp._flags`, not `fp._flags` (assuming `fp` is of type `*mut FILE`).

In addition, you'll probably need to wrap the access in an `unsafe` block, as dereferencing a raw pointer is always an unsafe operation. Try something like this:

```
let flags = unsafe { (*fp)._flags };
let is_unbuffered = (flags & libc::_IONBF as i16) != 0;
```