# Wrong mapping of C struct to Rust

Tags: rust, stdio, libc

For educational purpose I try to access the `FILE` struct in Rust:

```
unsafe {
    let passwd = libc::fopen("/etc/passwd".to_ptr(), &('r' as libc::c_char));
    let fp = &mut *(passwd as *mut MY_FILE);
    println!("flags={}, file={}", fp._flags, fp._file);
}
```

the `MY_FILE` struct I obtained by running bindgen on stdio.h (I'm on OS X):

```
bindgen /usr/include/stdio.h
```

Somehow `_flags` is always `8` for files open in write mode (4 in read mode), so this flags seems off (I tested with a `C` code to verify that it indeed is not 4 or 8). The file pointer however seems to be right. What could cause this? Am I extracting the binding from the wrong header file? Is there something I need to add to the `#[repr(C,)]` attribute?

[Here](https://gist.github.com/philippkeller/1f7cd1df9c48a5694c7e1e7c7952277d) is the full code including the struct.

This is a follow up question from [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38360996)

Comment: The code you posted doesn't compile (confusion of fp and passwd I think). Also, the strings you pass to the C function are not NUL-terminated, so your code has completely undefined behavior.

Comment: oh yes, I forgot to add one file which does the NUL termination, I've updated the gist above

Comment: Not worried about leaking the string every time? Anyway, I think the second argument has the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your implementation of `ToPtr` invites unsound code. Reproduced here:

```
// code in italics is wrong
impl ToPtr for str {
    fn to_ptr(&self) -> *const i8 {
        CString::new(self).unwrap().as_ptr()
    }
}
```

This allocates a new `CString` and returns a pointer to its contents, but the `CString` is dropped when `to_ptr` returns, so this is a dangling pointer. **Any dereference of this pointer is undefined behavior.** The [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/ffi/struct.CString.html#method.as_ptr) has a big warning about this, but it's still a very common mistake.

One correct way to make a `*const c_char` from a string literal is `b"string here\0".as_ptr() as *const c_char`. The string is null terminated and there is no dangling pointer because string literals live for the entire program. If you have a non-constant string to be converted, you *must* keep the `CString` alive while it is being used, like this:

```
let s = "foo";
let cs = CString::new(s).unwrap(); // don't call .as_ptr(), so the CString stays alive
unsafe { some_c_function(cs.as_ptr()); }
// CString is dropped here, after we're done with it
```

---

Aside: an editor "suggested" (I'm new to Stack Overflow, but it seems more polite to comment rather than try to rewrite my answer) that the above code could be written like this:

```
let s = "foo";
unsafe {
    // due to temporary drop rules, the CString will be dropped at the end of the statement (the `;`)
    some_c_function(CString::new(s).unwrap().as_ptr());
}
```

While this is technically correct (the best kind of correct), the "temporary drop rules" involved are subtle -- this works because `as_ptr` takes a reference to the `CString` <sup><sub>(actually a &CStr, because the compiler changes the method chain to CString::new(s).unwrap().deref().as_ptr())</sub></sup> instead of consuming it, and because we have only one C function to call. I don't like to rely on anything that's subtle or non-obvious when writing unsafe code.

---

With that out of the way, I [fixed that unsoundness](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a4deb83b9637054e75689a0097c0aea3) in your code (your calls all use string literals so I just used my first strategy above). I get this output on OSX:

```
0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 8, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 4, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

So, this matches your results, right? I also wrote the following C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    struct __sFILE *fp1 = fdopen(STDIN_FILENO, "r");
    struct __sFILE *fp2 = fdopen(STDOUT_FILENO, "w");
    struct __sFILE *fp3 = fdopen(STDERR_FILENO, "w");
    struct __sFILE *passwd = fopen("/etc/passwd", "r");

    printf("%i %i %i %i\n", fp1->_flags, fp2->_flags, fp3->_flags, passwd->_flags);
}
```

And got the output:

```
4 8 8 4
```

Which seems to vindicate the Rust results. There is a comment at the top of `/usr/include/stdio.h` that says:

```
/*
 * The following always hold:
 *
 *  if (_flags&(__SLBF|__SWR)) == (__SLBF|__SWR),
 *      _lbfsize is -_bf._size, else _lbfsize is 0
 *  if _flags&__SRD, _w is 0
 *  if _flags&__SWR, _r is 0
 */
```

And looking up those constants:

```
#define __SLBF  0x0001      /* line buffered */
#define __SRD   0x0004      /* OK to read */
#define __SWR   0x0008      /* OK to write */
```

This seems to match the output we get: 4 for file opened in read mode, 8 for write. So what is the problem here?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about the dangling pointer, those things are very important. It's in the doc and I didn't read. Then: the C code I had was from the advanced unix programming book. After I found out that most of the FILE struct variables are only filled upon stream reading/writing, I found this sentence in the book: "Note that we perform I/O on each stream before printing its buffering status, since the first I/O operation usually causes the buffers to be allocated for a stream" (again, RTFM to me..) Working gist: https://gist.github.com/philippkeller/c683dda9d89ca0f8cb6830b6dc52910b